# How to find detailed laptop specs?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, cpu

I'm having a hard time finding all the minor specs of different laptops. Most laptops just specify only few things like CPU, RAM , Graphics card, and few other specs in a generalized way. It gets more worse if we are shopping in online websites. Most of the times they say like 2 GB DDR3 ram but they don't give any clue about what the frequency is. And similar things like 320 GB hard disk without any rpm specified, WiFi b/g/n without any details specified like no of bands mimo speed etc,

Where can i find all these specs.

Say if i want to get a laptop with [Intel® Pentium® Processor 2117U 
(2M Cache, 1.80 GHz)](http://ark.intel.com/products/71469/Intel-Pentium-Processor-2117U-2M-Cache-1_80-GHz) . The CPU specs say that it has Intel My WiFi technology. Does it mean all laptops having this CPU will have Intel Centrino technology.

Are there any clues so I can find the specs easily.?

Comment: There is no single easy way. You will have to check the 'specs' page of of laptop on the manufacturers site to get some of the information. Usually followed by downloading the manual because the technical specs page also often contains insufficient information. :(

Comment: @bharat: Some web sites sell rebadged OEM (Clevo etc.) laptops and let you customise pretty much everything. For instance, in the UK: http://pcspecialist.co.uk/notebooks/optimusIV-15/

Answer (score 2):

Information like this will be hard, if not impossible to find.  Computer manufacturers are intentionally vague when it comes to hardware for a variety of reasons.  Most consumers do not care for or even understand the technical specifications.  Most manufacturers do put tech specs on a different tab, link, whatever.  However, that information also tends to be generic.  The reason is that allows the manufacturer to change the specs mid run.  Its not uncommon for a manufacturer to switch to a different ethernet card or other device during that models run.  Why?  Maybe the can get a better deal from a distributor, or perhaps that part is discontinued...